# Do we need a separate [scroll] tag beside the [magic-items] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have a [scroll](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scroll) tag with all of six questions (though one doesn't seem to deserve it).

Do we need this tag, or does [magic-items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items) suffice? Should it be merged with [magic-items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items) as a synonym?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is very little adoption of the tag, and the community usage seems to be to tag with [magic-items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items) instead, there being [29 questions about scrolls tagged that way](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20[magic-items]%20scroll).

Given the low adoption (showing a lack of need to single out scrolls with their own tag), no searchability advantage over `[magic-items] scroll`, and the lack of similar tags for specific kinds of magic items, we should make [scroll](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scroll) into a synonym of [magic-items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items).

Comment: After hitting a score of 10+ with little contention, I figure this is acceptable and have performed the merge. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score -1):

The lack of adoption means it’s probably unwarranted, but just to play Devil’s Advocate here:

In D&D 3.5e, at least, scrolls have a fair few rules specific to themselves, some of which are common sources of misunderstandings (scroll mishaps, what a nat-1 means for UMD with a scroll, etc.). There are also a number of classes with special features relating to scrolls, which could prompt questions about the best scrolls available for a certain purpose, perhaps.

Thus, it might be valid to think about questions about scrolls as a specific subset of those about magic items in general, and a meaningful distinction is possible.

...but the fact that people have not been using the tag suggests that, while possible, people have not found value in this distinction, which is why I have voted for d7’s answer.